# What is the KeyCode for ","(comma) and "."(dot) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums, keycode

In my `KeyDown` `EventHandler` I need to know what is the `KeyCode` for "," and ".".

I can't find them thats why I ask. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `KeyDown` and not the `KeyPress` handler?

Comment: The KeyDown event handler handles key strokes, not their representation in system, what depends on regional settings. To handle charakter, use KeyPress event.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A key and a character are not the same thing. The keyboard layout transforms between them, and that transform isn't trivial. Probably you're doing the wrong thing when using `KeyDown`. If you want to know which character a user entered you should use `KeyPress`, which gives the the already translated character.

For example `Keys.Decimal` is a key on the numpad that corresponds to `.` on the US layout, and `,` on the German layout. `Keys.Oemcomma` and `OemPeriod` are likely `,` and `.` belows the letters. But on other layouts that may be different.

Comment: Keys.Deciaml is for numpad what for second decimal??

Comment: There is no "second decimal". There is a key for *comma* and one for *period*, but which of them produces the decimal separator depends on the locale. I'm also quite sure that asking this question means you're already on the wrong track. You should work with characters, not keys.

Answer (score 10):

`Oemcomma` and `OemPeriod` look like good candidates.

Look at the [`Keys` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

I did this:

1. Created a WinForm project with a single textbox.
2. Added the keydown event handler.
3. Put a break point in it
4. Got this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out the decimal value, that's your key code.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Keys.Oemcomma` and `Keys.OemPeriod`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this "."c

A float filter:

```
Select Case e.KeyChar
    Case "0"c To "9"c
    Case "."c
        If .Text.Contains(".") Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    Case ChrW(Keys.Delete), ChrW(Keys.Back)
    Case Else
        e.Handled = True
End Select
```

Comment: Is there a C# syntax for this?