# How to get the '.' dot character KeyPressEvent on Android softkeyboard

Tags: java, android, keyevent, android-keypad

Hi I'm trying to get the event when I press `.` (dot) in android keyboard

```
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   if (keyCode == '.') {
        Log.d("dot pressed" "dot presed");
```

where I am getting wrong?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8915679/1911784

Comment: @OMAK That question is about .NET

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT) {
        Log.d("dot pressed" "dot presed");

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to detect via this too

Comment: Does not really help because '.' does not fire onKey**** at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PERIOD