# How to assign Control + . as a shortcut key?

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to catch keys in my *winform* `KeyDown` event and set <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> as a shortcut key.

But I can't find <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) key in `Keys` list.

```
private void frmMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.DOTKEY) //what is dot key
        //Do somthing
   }
```

Comment: How about you set a breakpoint, hit the `.` key, and see what turns up?

Comment: look this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915626/what-is-the-keycode-for-comma-and-dot-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keys.Decimal` on the US layout and `Keys.OemPeriod` on the German layout are what you're looking for.