# SendKeys not working with period character

Tags: .net, vb.net, sendkeys

I'm trying to send the period "." character with both SendKeys.Send and SendKeys.SendWait methods (and in both "." and "{.}" forms) and it just seems to not work (i.e. application hangs).

I'm having trouble just with the "dot" character, since other symbols are sent over without issues.

I also tried passing the Keys.OemPeriod enum value but what I got was to send either its string representation "OemPeriod" or numerical value 188, depending on the method I used (cast or ToString) since Send/SendWait accept just a String value.

PS If you're wondering, I'm implementing an Excel-like behaviour of converting the Keys.Decimal (numpad period) value to the current decimal separator, using a IMessageFilter object.

**EDIT**
After some tests I found that it works if a keyboard layout with a comma on the "Del" button of the numpad is set.
Seems like a conflict occurs when sending a "." and it is both Keys.OemPeriod and Keys.Decimal, but I need to discriminate between them to implement a consistent behaviour.

**EDIT2**

Here is some sample code of my filter prototype

```
Public Class DecimalKeyFilter
   Implements IMessageFilter

   Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100

   Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean _
      Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage

      If (m.Msg <> WM_KEYDOWN) Then Return False

      Dim key As Keys = DirectCast(m.WParam.ToInt32() And Keys.KeyCode, Keys)
      If (key <> Keys.Decimal) Then Return False

      Dim separator As String = CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
      SendKeys.Send(separator)
      Return True
   End Function
End Class
```

**EDIT3**

For the sake of completeness, I solved the problem by calling the native `SendInput` function, which appears to be the `SendKeys` underlying Win32 API, and which accepts the Virtual Key codes directly in `Short` format.
This strongens my doubt that a conflict is happening when a string representation that is mapped to multiple Virtual Keys is sent, which would render SendKeys a really poor API.
Anyway, this is just my hypothesis, so any further explanation to this behaviour is welcome

Comment: Please refine your question and show some code you did. What you are really looking for?

Comment: @Claudius I need a way to have _working_ code equivalent to `SendKeys.Send(".")`

Comment: @Claudius As I stated in the first two lines, it doesn't work, making my app hang. I tried sending both the string and the single character with the same resulting behaviour.

Comment: Do you even get to       SendKeys.Send(separator)?

Comment: @Claudius yes, I use to debug my code before asking quiestions.

Comment: that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915626/what-is-the-keycode-for-comma-and-dot-in-net

Comment: Maybe try this SendKeys.Send(ChrW(separator))

Comment: What happens if you try `SendKeys.Send("{" & separator & "}")`?

Comment: @VisualVincent works if `separator == ","` , not if `separator == "."`

Comment: Can downvoters just argue their vote?

Comment: Perhaps you should try something like [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) instead?

Comment: @VisualVincent see my last edit :)